# Flexbox items overlap while setting font-size with calc function

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-size

I have a simple HTML and CSS code. I am using CSS `calc` function to create fluid typography.
Hover when I make the window smaller, the image overlaps the text. The issue disappears when I use fixed font-size like `3rem` instead of `calc` function.

Is there any way to stop overlap while using CSS `calc` funciton?

```html
<div>
<h1>
This is a loooooong title
</h1>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Shaqi_jrvej.jpg/1200px-Shaqi_jrvej.jpg">
</div>
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


div img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
}

div h1 {
  /*It works when I set fixed font-size size like "3rem" */
      font-size: calc(1.625rem + 5.075vw); 
      width: 300px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n1gsj3x5/1/

[image: problem screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this, you can make two changes: add gap between the two elements and implement word-wrap strategy that way:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px; /* this is good to add  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  
div img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
}
  
div h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.625rem + 5.075vw); 
  width: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word; /* This is important */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just set a dynamic width to h1 like :

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap:5px;
}


div img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
}

div h1 {
     font-size: calc(1.625rem + 5.075vw); 
     width: calc(100% - 410px);
}
```

the h1 with gonna change if screen size change